# How can I serve Ionic app on a different port?

Tags: browser, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to run the ionic project on browser but the default port 8000 is already in use.

I need to change the port

I'm using this command:

```
ionic run browser --port 8002
```

**but its not working.**

The [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/run.html) says the `port` **options** are **--port|-p**

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with `ionic serve -p 8002` ?

Comment: yes I did, but this way does not open the individual window from the chrome like `ionic run browser`

Comment: Try ionic serve --port 8002

Comment: @AnnaBelle he,yes! it's on the answer already! appreciate the help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try `ionic platform add browser` before,

or

`ionic serve -p 8002 --dev-logger-port 8103`

instead...

Comment: why when I request ionic serve -p 8100 I get see it switch to 8101?

 ionic serve -p 8100 --no-open --allow-file-access-from-files --target cordova
> ionic-app-scripts.cmd serve --address localhost --port 8101 --livereload-port 35730 --dev-logger-port 53704 --nobrowser

Comment: 2nd answer worked for me

Answer (score 22):

When running 2 ionic apps at the same time, it's not enough to specify a new port for the second app, you also need to specify a **new port** for **live reload** and **dev logger** or they will conflict with the first app:

```
ionic serve -p 8101 -r 8102 --dev-logger-port 8103
```

Otherwise, you'll get connection error.  Make sure firewall allows all those ports you use.

Answer (score 8):

```
ionic serve -p 9000
```

or

```
ionic serve --port 9000
```

simple

Answer (score 6):

`ionic serve --external --host="0.0.0.0" --port="8132"`
that works for me (im running ionic on **docker**)

ionic  version : **4.7.1** 
ionic cli version : **5.4.16**

Answer (score 2):

according to the issue tracker from the ionic team.. running commands like

```
ionic cordova run browser --port 8080
```

currently dont work, it seems to be a known issue and needs to be fixed within some cli version, not sure when this will be

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2307

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2312

Answer (score 0):

you can also specify port and run in lab version using this command:
 `ionic serve -l --port 2020`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`ionic serve -p 8200 -i 35730`